# CSS Specificity in Angular Component using /deep/ when a class is outside the component

Tags: css, angular, sass

I made a button component for a Angular Component Library I am putting together. The button works well and the component is implemented like so:

```
<sio-button
    [buttonLabel]="'Button Text'"
    [buttonFormat]="'fluid'"
    [buttonStyle]="'1L'"
    (buttonClicked)="outputButtonClick()" >
</sio-button>
```

As you can see I pass through various values via the `Input()` decorator and the button style is set using a short-hand string value, the template looks like so and a method is used to output the desired CSS classes as a string

    {{buttonLabel}}

the rendered output looks like so -

```
<sio-button _ngcontent-c0="" _nghost-c2="" ng-reflect-button-label="Button Text" ng-reflect-button-format="compact"
    ng-reflect-button-style="primary-line">
    <button _ngcontent-c2="" class="sio-btn sio-btn--primary-line sio-btn--compact" ng-reflect-klass="sio-btn"
        ng-reflect-ng-class="sio-btn--primary-line sio-btn-"> Button Text
    </button>
</sio-button>
```

I want to all the user of the UI components library to use my buttons as a button group, this is simple, I just wrap a DIV with a set CSS class so I can amend the CSS of the buttons within as I need to remove the border-right and border-left on the first button and last button contained within the button group like so...

```
<div class="sio-btn-group">
    <sio-button [buttonLabel]="'Button Left'" [buttonFormat]="'compact'" [buttonStyle]="'1L'">
    </sio-button> <!-- this needs to lose its borfer-right -->
    <sio-button [buttonLabel]="'Button Middle'" [buttonFormat]="'compact'" [buttonStyle]="'1L'">
    </sio-button>
    <sio-button [buttonLabel]="'Button Right'" [buttonFormat]="'compact'" [buttonStyle]="'1L'">
    </sio-button> <!-- this needs to lose its border-left -->
</div>
```

So in my `sio-button` SCSS file I wish to write the CSS rule to overwrite the borders for the first and last child (remember that the `sio-btn-group` DIV is outside the button component) so in my `button.component.scss` file I add the following

```
/deep/.sio-btn-group .sio-btn--primary-line {
  &:first-of-type  {
    border-right: none;
  }

  &:last-of-type  {
    border-left: none;
  }
}
```

And this doesn't work as the styles are overwritten on all 3 button components. So I change this to

```
/deep/.sio-btn-group .sio-btn--primary-line {
  &:first-child  {
    border-right: none;
  }

  &:last-child  {
    border-left: none;
  }
}
```

This has the same effect as all buttons contained within the `.sio-btn-group` have their left and right borders removed. If I remove the /deep/ it doesn't work at all and should I add a second `/deep/` like so `/deep/.sio-btn-group /deep/.sio-btn--primary-line` all the left and right borders are removed. What is wrong with my CSS selector? If anyone can help me see what I am doing wrong I would be most appreciative.

If you feel I should add a code pen please says so and I shall add one or should my explanation be confusing please let me know and I shall reword.

Comment: I think I have found the answer, the selector should be (in CSS not SCSS yet)

`/deep/.sio-btn-group sio-button:first-of-type .sio-btn--primary-line {
  border-right: none;
}

/deep/ .sio-btn-group sio-button:last-of-type .sio-btn--primary-line {
  border-left: none;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed my problem

```
/deep/.sio-btn-group sio-button {

      &:first-of-type {

        [class*="-line"] {
          border-right: none;
        }
      }

      &:last-of-type {

        [class*="-line"] {
          border-left: none;
        }
      }
    }
```